# putting a custom button on a nav bar in ios6 not working

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have researched this a lot and have used a couple of different approaches.  This code is located in my `ViewController.m`:

1)1st Approach

```
UIImage *settingsimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gearicon"];
  UIBarButtonItem *settingsBarButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:settingsimage style:(UIBarButtonItemStylePlain) target:self action:@selector(switchpages)];

  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = settingsBarButton;
```

this code executes without any errors, but no button appears!

2)  2nd Approach

```
UIButton *settingbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [settingbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(switchpages) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [settingbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gearicon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *newBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:settingbtn];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBarItem;
```

Same as above, no errors, but no button.  Please help where I've gone wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: are you sure the image name is gearicon.png (spelling and all lower case)?

Comment: @calvinBhai. funny thing...I'm sure the spelling is correct, etc.  BUT..I thought of that too..so i just made up some name that wasn't in my project..code went right non.  no issues.

Comment: Have you logged settingsimage to see that it's not nil?

Comment: @rdelmar.  Thanks for the idea....I'm new to xcode and instruments but will see if I can figure out how to do that.  when I stepped through the code, I only saw hex values for settingsimage, etc.  I assumed those were the memory locations and not the values.

Comment: @rdelmar.  So there is what I get when I break at the load of the image:settingsimage UIImage * 0x005caa77 absurd value:(info =7, value=23722.  Any ideas on what that is telling me?

Comment: You don't need instruments to check for nil. Just put a log statement after that first line, NSLog(@"%@",settingsImage), and see what it gives you.

Comment: @rdelmar  Thanks.  here is what I got: <UIImage: 0x714010>  mean anything to you?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: It means you have a valid image object. I don't know why that first method isn't working, I tried it and it worked fine.

Comment: @rdelmar.  Are you using a simple NavigationBar and have the code in the .m file for the ViewController?

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to the `ImageView` with image behind the button, it will do the trick

If you are not using any NavigationController and want to see how to add NavigationItem to the NavigationBar then you should make sure you add a NavigationBar on you xib and connect the IBOutlet in the Connection Inspector of it.  here how your classes & code would look like...

in your `.h` file

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIImageView *navigationImageView;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIButton *navigationButton;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
```

in `.m` file

```
@synthesize navigationButton;
@synthesize navigationImageView;
@synthesize navBar;
```

First create an ImageView and add the custom image inside if you are using the button with image

```
UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
self.navigationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backImage];
```

now set the frame of the image view to the image

```
 [self.navigationImageView setFrame: CGRectMake(5, 7, backImage.size.width, backImage.size.height)];
```

create the custom button and assign the image

```
self.navigationButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.navigationButton setImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

add image view to the navigation bar

```
[self.navBar addSubview:self.navigationImageView];

[self.navBar addSubview:self.navigationButton];
[self.navBar bringSubviewToFront:self.navigationButton];
```

create a `UIBarButtonItem` with the button as a custom view for custom method

```
  UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.navigationButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
    [self.navigationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and finally your custom backMethod whatever you want to do in this... for testing you can show alert

```
-(void)backMethod{
    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"custom navigation" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

Comment: @nsguliver.  I'll have to give that a try.  In all the research I've seen..I haven't seen this approach.  By the way...I have my code running in ViewDidLoad.  Do you think the Nav bar is overlaying the button I'm creating?

Comment: this is sometime quite tricky, i have had issue dealing with navigation bar buttons, i just able to try some work around how i have presented

Comment: @nsguiliver...so I tried your code and ran into a problem on the second and third lines.  I receive:
Property 'navigationImageView" not found on object of type "TCViewController".  I'm putting this code in my main view TCViewController.m.  Is that the correct place?

Comment: you need to add this imageview as property to your class or you need to declare it yourself when adding, i have both as property on the class `@property(strong,nonatomic)UIImageView *navigationImageView;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIButton *navigationButton;`

Comment: @SteveM check my updated code, it should help you, it is actually a working code

Comment: @nsguliver  Thanks for the additional details. That got me past the errors.  Code runs but still no button.  So...I set a break at the UIImage load  and here's what I get: 0x005cba77 absurd value:(info=7, value=23738.  I'm guessing there's the issue, but my .png file works fine an image on one of the Bar Items Apple provides. Ideas?

Comment: try with some other image, i think it might be something with the image you are using?

Comment: @nsguliver  I have tried that...same thing.  in fact, i can make up a name of an image file that's not even in my project and the code goes right through it.  no errors...??? how is that possible?

Comment: i am afraid if the above code is not working then you might be doing something wrong, you should make sure you have all the things set up properly, if you have problem, try to make a simple application with navigation controller and create a custom navigation button on that. it would help i am sure

Comment: @nsguliver so one thing...I didn't put a navigation controller in my xib...just a navigation bar.  could that be the issue?

Comment: @SteveM if you are trying to add your own custom UINavigationBar and not using NavigaitonController then you should make sure that you are connecting this UINavigationBar as IBOutlet, and in the above code where i used NavigationController then you would need to use your navigationBar

Comment: @SteveM I can update the code according to your scenario, and it will work, just look the updated code in few moments

Comment: @nsguliver  Got it working!  Graphic shows up perfectly, BUT..not action on pressing.  Doesn't invoke the method i have setup to catch the press.  Any other ideas...then I'll leave ya alone. Thank you!

Comment: @SteveM check out my code, updated the sample backMethod, now it will show you an alert when you press the button. and please accept the answer!

Comment: @nsguliver  it's not the method...the button can't be pressed.  just shows up, but can't take any action.  I have the code exactly as you have it.

Comment: thats weird, if you have followed step by step all the methods and if you are adding the button then it should be press-able. make sure you are adding the UIButton there & bring it to the front from navBar, i have same code and it shows the alert. i think you need to learn objective-c first and how it works then try stuff...

Comment: @nsguliver...maybe so, but my entire app is done except for this frustrating thing.  Thanks for you help...you got me further than I was.

Comment: you are not far from making it work, it is some small mistake you are still doing, check your button is it adding properly and you added the selector for the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

Comment: @nsguliver...the selector is there.  No errors compiling.  I'll keep working on it.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, here is my final solution.  This puts a "gear" icon in the upper right hand side of a NavigationBar without a border:

.h

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *settingsbtn;
 @property(strong, nonatomic)UIButton *navigationButton;
```

.m

```
 @synthesize navigationButton;
 @synthesize settingsbtn;
 @synthesize navBar;
```

ViewDidLoad

```
//custom settings button
navigationButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[navigationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(swithpages)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[navigationButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gearicon.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[navigationButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 35)];
UIBarButtonItem *settingsbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:navigationButton];

settingsbtn.rightBarButtonItem = settingsbutton;
```

The only thing I'm missing is having the button "glow" (like Apple's Remote App) upon pressed instead of color changing by default.